# Jquery doesn't work on HTML tags which via called by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have an unordered list

```
<ul id="showlist"></ul>
```

if user calls ajax function this  fills with list items like

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li> 
</ul>
```

my problem begins after that. i have a `<script>` tag at the very and of my page. it says when down button is pressed make first child of `<ul>` blue. but it does nothing

```
<script>

$(body).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        $("#showlist:first-child").attr("style","background-color:blue");       
    }
})

</script>
```

how can i solve my problem?

Comment: jQuery is unaware that you have added items to the DOM so you need to use on() to account for this. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @JayBlanchard He's not attempting to bind the handler to the dynamic elements, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: See @JasonP's answer below, body needs to be in quotes - 'body'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$('body')` instead of `$(body)`.

You also have an issue with your selector:

```
$("#showlist li:first-child")
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hF6LF/

Also, you mentioned in your post that this script is at the end of the page. If you had the script in the head, you would need to wait for dom ready for the `body` element to exist. It might be safer to bind the handler to `document`, which will always exist.

Comment: now you got it. $("#showlist li:first-child") has solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use .on jquery method

```
$(body).on("keydown", function(e) {
   .....
});
```

[Jquery .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: That is what i get for trying to answer the question i thought he asked:)

Comment: `.on("keydown", function() {})` is equivalent to `.keydown(function() {})`. So your suggestion will make no difference to what the OP already has. (If you were trying to suggest a delegated handler you would need to supply a selector as the second argument to `.on()`, but that isn't needed here given that the OP is already trying to bind the handler to the body.)

Answer (score -1):

Yo have to use the on event listener which can handle events on descendant elements not yet created.

See https://api.jquery.com/on/

For example something like the following.

```
$(document).on( "keydown", "body", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: He's not attempting to bind the handler to the dynamic elements, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: Ah yes. So actually after re-reading, the fix would be to use  $("#showlist li:first-child")